# Android apks file contains serial number of build-PC?

Tags: android, apk

My professor said to me that when you build apk the serial number of the computer or of the cpu that built the APK is written in the file

My question is if it’s true where it’s written?
Because I think it’s might be wrong

I tried to decompile the apk
And search inside the files
I tried using 7zip too

Comment: Never heard of something like this. The only place I can image would be in the DEX files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dealt with APK structure and building, and have never heard of something like that, to be honest. Has he mentioned, which file should be affected? The APK in a whole or a specific file within the APK? And in which step of APK building this happens?

The closest I can think of would be the mechanism to [provide alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) to support specific device configurations. But that still hasn't to do anything with any kind of serial number for the computer the APK was built on.